# django rest add data to serializer when saving

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I want to do the following:

models.py

```
class MyModel(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

serializers.py

```
class MyModelSerializerCreate(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            'name',
        )
```

And I would like to add as owner the current user in `request.user`.
Currently I am adding this in my view directly by uptading request.data with user and then pass the updated data to my serializer.

```
    data = request.data
    # Add owner to data
    data["owner"] = request.user.pk
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
```

I would like to do this in my serializer directly but can't find a way to properly do it because it looks like data validation to me. Is this a good idea ? Should I keep this logic in my views or move it to my serializer ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get a user from serializer context:

`self.context['request'].user`
It is passed from a method `get_serializer_context` which originally created in a `GenericAPIView`:

```
class GenericAPIView(APIView):
    ....
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        """
        Extra context provided to the serializer class.
        """
        return {
            'request': self.request,
            'format': self.format_kwarg,
            'view': self
        }
```

Inside a serializer you need to override a `create` method:

```
class MyModelSerializerCreate(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name', )
 
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['owner'] = self.context['request'].user
        return super(MyModelSerializerCreate, self).create(validated_data)
```

You could also override an `update` and `delete` methods if you need some special interactions with the `User` model.

Comment: Hum this looks good but it overrides the create function of the ModelSerializer which does a lot of things like managing many_to_many relationship for example. It would be cool if I could put my user directly into validated_data

Comment: @v.thorey so you could update `validated_data` and then call `super` for provide all default behavior or you could use `perform_create` method in you view. I'll update my answer

Comment: @IvanSemochkin I have the same problem, but your answer somehow doesn't work for me.
I basically want to do:
`def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)`
But if I do what you answered I get the error: 
`"user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]`

Comment: @J.Hesters maybe you have a `user` in a `fields` tuple so `validate` method want you to provide a user before `create`

Comment: @IvanSemochkin Thank you! I was struggling with the Error-Message that `user` is required, but it was not because the Model requires it, but the `fields` of the serializer specified it as required.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunatly I dont have the reputation points to comment on @ivan-Semochkin post above,  but should the last line not be:

```
return super(MyModelSerializerCreate, self).create(validated_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution from Ivan Semochkin did not work for me, as it never entered into the `create()` method of the serializer. As `request.data` field is immutable, you need to copy it and then extend it.

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
from rest_framework.request import Request

class MyModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    def _extend_request(self, request):
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data['owner'] = request.user
        request_extended = Request(HttpRequest())
        request_extended._full_data = data

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request_extended = self._extend_request(request)
        return super().create(request_extended, *args, **kwargs)
```