# Django Rest: Add data to a "required" field automatically

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, httprequest

I want to automatically assign a value for a required field in Django Rest framework, without the value having to be given in the post request.

My View:

```
class WaitercallCreate(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = WaitercallCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
```

The Serializer:

```
class WaitercallCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Waitercall
        fields = ('order', 'user', 'done', 'type_of_call')

    read_only_fields = ('user', 'done')
```

Users should be able to do a postrequest, only giving their token in the header and the order id as the body.
I want to set the value for user by default to the requests user.
I tried overwriting the perform_create method in my view like this:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

This didn't work. Then I tried overwriting the create method in the view like this:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        data['user'] = request.user
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Which also didn't work, because Orderdicts are immutable. For the first (and the last try, read further) I always get the same response:

```
{
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Lastly I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346200/django-rest-add-data-to-serializer-when-saving) stackoverflow post, which recommends overwriting the create method in the serializer. Like this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    print(self.context['request'].user)
    validated_data['user'] = self.context['request'].user
    return super(WaitercallCreateSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

It also gave me the same response. I'm lost. What can I try next?

Comment: You need to exclude the fields you're supplying manually from the `fields` list.

Answer (score 4):

The error is coming from the serializer validation, which is called before the `create` method is called. Therefore, the changes to the `create` method are not making a difference. You can fix this by calling out that the `user` field is not required in the serializer. This will look like:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class WaitercallCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.JSONField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Waitercall
        fields = ('order', 'user', 'done', 'type_of_call')
        read_only_fields = ('user', 'done')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Will this work, even if the user is a foreignkey? Or will I have to user a primarykeyrealtedfield?

Answer (score 2):

I was also having same issue as yours. If you are using Generic views then do this:

**Views:**

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

**Serializer:**

You just have to add this in you serializer in order to save the user. `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` is used to represent the target of the relationship using its primary key. `read_only=True` to make this field read only.

```
class WaitercallCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Waitercall
        fields = ('order', 'user', 'done', 'type_of_call')
```